# Load Ckeditor plugin icon from local path

Tags: angularjs, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to add   [youtube plugin](https://github.com/fonini/ckeditor-youtube-plugin) plugin to Ckeditor4, anyway the plugins works fine but the icon in the toolbar is not shwoing at all.
This is the first part of code inside **/youtube/plugin.js** that define the youtube button on the toolbar:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('youtube', {
    lang: [ 'en', 'bg', 'pt', 'pt-br', 'ja', 'hu', 'it', 'fr', 'tr', 'ru', 'de', 'ar', 'nl', 'pl', 'vi', 'zh', 'el', 'he', 'es', 'nb', 'nn', 'fi', 'et', 'sk', 'cs', 'ko', 'eu' ],
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.addCommand('youtube', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('youtube', {
            allowedContent: 'div{*}(*); iframe{*}[!width,!height,!src,!frameborder,!allowfullscreen]; object param[*]; a[*]; img[*]'
        }));

        editor.ui.addButton('Youtube', {
            label : editor.lang.youtube.button,
            toolbar : 'insert',
            command : 'youtube',
            icon : this.path + 'images/icon.png'  //here console.log(this.path) return  http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.0/standard/plugins/youtube/
        });
```

Normally when we add a new plugin such as the  [youtube plugin](https://github.com/fonini/ckeditor-youtube-plugin) All we need is to change the path is to add these part of code into configuration:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('youtube', '../../node_modules/ckeditor-youtube-plugin/youtube/');

    $rootScope.ckEditorOptions = { //ckEditorOptions represent my config variable
        allowedContent : true,
        extraPlugins: 'youtube',

        toolbar_full: [  

            {name: 'youtube', items: ['Youtube']},

        ],
        language: 'fr',
```

I noticed then, unfortunately the  `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal` in the first line is not working right and because that line role is to define our path `this.path` who should not point to the CDN.

I'm sure that i'm missing something because when I try to edit manually the `icon : this.path` to `icon : http://anylink.png` the icon is showed.

Comment: I think you just answered your question at the end... just set the relative path to your image in the icon setting. That is what I did and it worked.